# Javascript Observable -> delete items of array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, rxjs, observable

I have a problem for deleting items of my observable.

products$: Observable<Product[]>;

There's the value: [image]
We can see 2 types of object: With 'normal' name and with ID like name.
All the objects with the name starts by 'ID...' is a child reference of a product and i would like to delete all them.

How can I do this with Rxjs or vanilla js? 
Thanks in advance :) !

Comment: Write a filter, use a regex/strings starts with kind of function to filter out all the unwanted data. And don't post images post a valid JSON so that people can write a sample for you in answer.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @pavankumar Thanks for your response. I thought an image would be easier but I will know it for the next time :). Thanks !

Comment: @wentjun Did you really need the code for that? Anyway, the problem is solved, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sth like

```
const hasRealName = (row) => !row.name.startsWith('ID');

const filteredProducts$: Observable<Product[]> = products$.pipe(
    map(
        rows => rows.filter(hasRealName)
    );
```

Comment: THANKS! My code works and i had understand your process :)